# Graph api /sites?search : some sites are not returned

Tags: javascript, azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have trouble with the graph api /sites?search= call.

In fact, my request returns only 11 sites out of 16. I don't see the difference between these sites that could explain this.
I connect with the credentials of an application (client secret) on the api and I have the Sites.ReadWriteAll (Application) permission.

Maybe the application doesn't have access to certain sites and needs to be explicitly granted somewhere on Azure? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are all sites in the same geo or do you have multi-geo sites?

Comment: All sites are in the same geo.

Comment: To be honest, I've started using GetAllSites endpoint with filtering. It seems to me that results are more consistence, but it lists only root sites, not subsites: `GET /v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$filter=contains(displayName,' call')`

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **Sites.ReadWrite.All** permission of Application type:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call graph API with **search** query, I got only **16** sites out of 21:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

**Response:**

[image]

As *@user2250152* suggested, you can make use of **`GetAllSites`** endpoint to list all sites across geographies in an organization.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$count=true
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got the **same results** when I used below graph call as all sites are in same geographic location:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$count=true
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the difference between these sites, I observed `/sites?search=` call won't return sites that are created for user's **personal OneDrive accounts** that looks like:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_xxxxxxxxx_onmicrosoft_com
```

This `/sites?search=` call also won't return below **search** site:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/search
```

But **`GetAllSites`** and **`ListAllSites`** endpoint returns all these sites in response.

**Reference:**

[Try to retrieve all sites, but in some cases, some sites are not found in the search - Microsoft Q&A by **RajeshKumar-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/887441/try-to-retrieve-all-sites-but-in-some-cases-some-s)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All & Sites. Selected Permissions. If you don't have the permission to the site, you will be unable to search the site